# How to pass custom parameters between FCGI servers in C via NGINX?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

**Intro**

My FastCGI servers are written in C. I would like the `FCGI` auth server to pass some custom parameters (such as some parameters returned by a Radius server) to a `FCGI "back-end"` server.

**My Question**

Does NGINX support passing custom parameters between two FCGI servers in C? If yes, I would appreciate some help on the following:

1. how to program the FCGI auth server to pass the variable to NGINX.
2. how to program the FCGI back-end server to read the custom parameters
3. how to configure the nginx.conf file. In my example below, I have "fastcgi_param CUSTOM_PARAM custom_param;". I don't know whether that is the way to do it, I went by how it is done with a HTTP header parameter.

**curent work**

This is what I have. The FCGI /auth server would set the `custom_param variable`, and I would like NGINX to forward this variable to the FCGI back-end server.

```
location / {
    auth_request /auth;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location = /auth {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param CUSTOM_PARAM custom_param;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9010;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Authentication handlers pass information back to the server via http headers. With nginx you'll use `auth_request_set` to assign those values to variables:

```
location / {
    auth_request /auth;
    auth_request_set $receive_from_auth $upstream_http_x_custom_param;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Sending parameters to FCGI from nginx works the way you indicated:

```
location = /auth {
    include fastcgi_params;
    set $send_to_auth yourvalue; 
    fastcgi_param CUSTOM_PARAM $send_to_auth;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9010;
}
```

And those parameters are read from the environment:

```
char *custom_param;
custom_param = getenv("CUSTOM_PARAM");
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for the example. How should the auth handler set the variable? I am asking because my back-end server does not see the value I assigned in the auth handler. My auth handler has "int custom_param = 100;". In the back-end server, I have a printf of getenv("CUSTOM_PARAM"); It showed a value of 0.

Comment: In the first example `auth_request_set` is reading the header _from_ your FCGI auth handler. I think the confusion may be coming from the two examples using the same variable, I'll clarify it.

Comment: I am not clear on how I should set the variable in my fastcgi auth handler code. I have: printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
//      "custom_param: 100\r\n"
        "custom-param: 100\r\n" ...); Also, the back-end server still reads the value using getenv(), so who will be using the $receive_from_auth variable? Thanks.

Comment: The way the example is written, it will read the X-Custom-Param header from your handler, or you could change it to $upstream_http_custom_param. But I may be misunderstanding your intentions, if nothing will read the $receive_from_auth variable, do you really need to send data back from fcgi?

Comment: The fcgi auth handler contacts a Radius server which returns some custome parameters (e.g. idle-timer). I would like these parameters to be passed to the fcgi back-end server. I am not sure on how to code the fcgi auth handler to pass the idle-timer param to nginx so nginx can hand it to the fcgi back-end. In the auth handler C code, I have         printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
        "X-Custom-Param: 100\r\n"
In the fcgi back-end server code, I have a printf of getenv("CUSTOM_PARAM") and it showed 0. I guess the "send $send_to_auth yourvalue" is no necessary? Thank you.

Comment: I think you may need to post a stripped down version of your auth handler so we can see what's going on.